# NSDate - How does the default initializer allocate space on the heap?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I know it's good practice to explicitly alloc and init objects, but I'm confused why it is not needed for instances of NSDate in the following example:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
```

Appears to be the same as this...

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

I assume the date class method allocates space on the heap, but I have only found NSDate.h and not how Apple actually implemented the method.

Apple documentation simply says, "This method uses the default initializer method for the class, init."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+[NSDate date] is a "convenience constructor". Typically the implementation will look very similar to `return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease]`.